# Laravel order by count of related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Restaurant` and a `Restaurant` has one or more `Order`. How can I get the top restaurants with the most orders? Lets say the top 5.

I'm not quite sure how I can accomplish this with a Eloquent Model.

edit:

with a raw query I can find the correct query to build.

```
SELECT 
    R.name, count(O.id) as total
FROM restaurants AS R
LEFT JOIN orders as O ON R.id = O.restaurant_id
GROUP BY R.id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But I don't know how I can create this with `Fluent`

It looks like I found what I was looking for:

```
return Restaurant::select(['*', DB::raw('count(orders.id) as total')])
->leftJoin('orders', 'restaurants.id', '=', 'orders.restaurant_id')
->groupBy('restaurants.id')
->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
->limit(5);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do your `models` look like? We need to see some code to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the answer to Topic Start.